# Intuitive representation of partial orders

Tags: order-theory

Is there any way to describe equivalence classes of partial orders for a set, in a somewhat intuitive way that makes it relatively easy to visualize their structure?

To clarify: I *don't* mean to count partial orders only up to isomorphism; i.e., I a 2-element set to have 3 different partial orders.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to count the partial orders on a set of labelled objects; is that correct?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, but not just count: actually describe each of the equivalence classes.

Comment: You’re not going to be able to do that for an underlying set with more than a handful of elements, labelled or not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was thinking maybe there's some kind of structure like partition the entire set into subsets, define full order on the subsets, and no order within subsets, etc. Of course, this specific approach won't work, but isn't there something that would, along these lines?

Comment: I don’t see anything. Yes, you can collapse elements to get a smaller, simpler partial order if the elements have the same predecessors and successors, but this just gets you a partial order in which no two distinct elements have identical predecessors and successors, and there are lots of those, starting with all linear orders and power set orders.